# Return list of strings with mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple query with PHP that returns a list of Strings with all the names of the users, but I can figure out how to do do it. The only thing i thought wa this:

```
<?php

$host_name  = "hostname";
$database   = "database";
$user_name  = "username";
$password   = "pass";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$select = "SELECT username from userstasker";

$result = $connect->query($select);
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

$connect->close();
?>
```

But this returns a JSon, ant idea how to do it?

Comment: It returns a json because.... `echo json_encode($rows);`

Comment: What do you mean by a "list"? HTML `<li>` tags, or just rows of text, or what?

Comment: Sorry i was not clear, i wanted an array

Comment: `$rows[] = $r['username'];`

Comment: Then comment out the `echo json_encode($rows);` and access the array `$rows`

Comment: `$rows` is already an array - how do you want to display it?

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot I just didn't know how to display it, thanks guys for the tips, the next time I will do my research before posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$host_name  = "hostname";
$database   = "database";
$user_name  = "username";
$password   = "pass";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$select = "SELECT username from userstasker";

$result = $connect->query($select);
$usernames = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $usernames[] = $r["username"];
}

$connect->close();

// Do something with $usernames

?>
```